# Create excel file with table of contents Spring boot java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I technically know how to create xls with sheet. But i'm having a problem creating a table of contents for every sheet in my excel.

Example is below this message. 
As you can see there's a sheet name and rows with corresponding name of sheet(ex. Sheet1,Sheet2). 
Is there also a possible syntax where I can link Sheet1 to Sheet1 ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What your screenshot shows are hyperlinks of type [HyperlinkType.DOCUMENT](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/common/usermodel/HyperlinkType.html#DOCUMENT). There is a `HyperlinkExample.java` in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/. There also is shown how to create a hyperlink to a target sheet and cell in the same workbook.

Comment: that's wow. thanks let me check the link i'll update you later. God bless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your screenshot shows are hyperlinks of type [HyperlinkType.DOCUMENT](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/common/usermodel/HyperlinkType.html#DOCUMENT). There is a `HyperlinkExample.java` in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/. There also is shown how to create a hyperlink to a target sheet and cell in the same workbook.

What you additional needs to know to create what your screenshot shows is:

Creating workbook, sheets, rows and cells. Setting cell contents. Setting AutoFilter. Setting column widths.

That all is shown in [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html). Complete examples for most of that also in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/ and/or in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/examples/.

Complete example creating exactly what your screenshot shows:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.HyperlinkType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelLinkedSheetsTOC {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
   FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx")
   //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
   //FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xls")
                                                                      ) {

   // we need creation helber for creating the links
   CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

   // hyperlink cell style
   CellStyle hlink_style = workbook.createCellStyle();
   Font hlink_font = workbook.createFont();
   hlink_font.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
   hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
   hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);

   // create 6 sheets
   Sheet sheet = null;
   for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet" + i);
   }
   // create sheet "Source" as the 7th sheet
   sheet = workbook.createSheet("Source");

   // create sheet "Table of Contents"
   sheet = workbook.createSheet("Table of Contents");
   // unselect first sheet
   workbook.getSheetAt(0).setSelected(false);
   // make "Table of Contents" the new first sheet
   workbook.setSheetOrder("Table of Contents", 0);
   // make "Table of Contents" the active sheet
   workbook.setActiveSheet(0);
   // create header row
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellValue("#");
   cell = row.createCell(2);
   cell.setCellValue("Sheet Name");

   // create content rows
   String sheetName = "";
   Hyperlink link = null;
   int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
   for (int i = 1; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(i);
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue(i);
    cell = row.createCell(2);
    sheetName = workbook.getSheetName(i);
    cell.setCellValue(sheetName);
    // create hyperlink to cell A1 in sheet with sheetName
    link = creationHelper.createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.DOCUMENT);
    link.setAddress("'" + sheetName + "'!A1");
    cell.setHyperlink(link);
    // style the link cell
    cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);
   }

   // set AutoFilter as shown in image
   sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(
    0, numberOfSheets-1, 1, 2)
   );

   // set column widths
   sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 5 * 256);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 5 * 256);
   sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 15 * 256);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Im just having problem with populating the sheet with different values from POJO. Hope you can help me with that .

Comment: @Lep: Please ask a specific new question about that. Please include a description of your problem in that new question. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? And please provide code you have tried in form of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).